# How to auto fill increasing values between existing filled cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

the situation is like this:

```
0
-
-
0
-
-
-
-
0
-
-
-
0
```

I wanted to be like this:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
0
```

There are thousands of cells in the range and this cannot be done manually.

Comment: Do the hyphens in the before representation indicate hyphens, or do they indicate empty cells?

Answer (score 2):

If the cells between the zeros are empty, you could do this:

Select all cells in your spreadsheet, then hit F5, click "Special", tick "Blanks" and hit OK. Now all blank cells are selected.

Without changing the selection, start typing

```
=if(
```

hit the up arrow, then type

```
=0,1,
```

hit the up arrow, then type

```
+1)
```

It will look something like this:

[image]

Hold down the Ctrl Key and hit Enter. Now all the previously empty cells will have a formula like

```
=if(A1=0,1,A1+1)
```

and cells between zeros will be numbered. Note that this works for several columns at once.

[image]

The formula in Jason Aller's post does not work for me at all. For completeness' sake here is that formula in a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I like the in place nature of this solution as compared to my addition of a temporary column to the right. I've grown used to using the column to the right when I'm going to end up using paste as values to overwrite the source data, but in cases where one is adding data in the gaps between existing data this is a very useful technique to know.

Comment: (1) Why are you proposing a multi-column answer to a one-column question?  (I found that confusing on first read.)  (2) Once the blank cells (*only* the blank cells) have been selected, `=A1+1` suffices.

Comment: (1) I'm showing that the approach does work for multi-column ranges. It also works for single column ranges, of course. (2) Checking for 0 will make sure that the incrementing numbers are only added below cells with a 0 value, not cells with text.

Answer (score 1):

Insert an empty column to the right of this column and add a formula that will look at the cell to the left and if that cell is a zero it will place a zero, and if not it will add one to the value in the cell above. Then copy the column and paste as values over the source column and delete the added column.

For example if your column is column A in cell B2 place:

```
=if(A2=0,0,B1+1)
```

and if the cells between the zeros are empty and do not have a hyphen in them then the formula can be changed to:

```
=if(AND(A2=0, NOT(ISBLANK(A2))), 0, B1+1)
```

Comment: Ditto.⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠

Comment: Did you test this? Where are the ascending numbers? All results are zero.

Comment: I hadn't tested the first formula, but I did test it prior to my edit with the presence of non empty cells between the zeros, and then added the version to differentiate between cells with no value and cells with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

If the only items in the column are zero and blanks and the first item is a zero, then select the cells you wish to process and run this small macro:

```
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
   Dim r As Range, K As Long, CH As String
   K = 1
   For Each r In Selection
      CH = r.Text
      If CH = "" Then
         r.Value = K
         K = K + 1
      Else
         K = 1
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]